# Is there a word or phrase for when you're at the whim of someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a short bio of my character who has made a contract with a demon and is now required to do her bidding. He's not necessarily a slave, he still has the freedom to do whatever he likes, I guess it's kind of like a DnD warlock-patron type of relationship where she occasionally has tasks for him to do and he's bound by contract to complete them. The sentence I'm writing is like "[Character] made a contract with the demon [Demon Name] and is now [word or phrase I can't think of] to her bidding."

I swear there's just a single word for it (I keep thinking of words like "vulnerable" and "liable" but they're not really right), not a phrase (though if you can think of one that fits then I might end up using it if I can't figure out the word), and it feels like it's on the tip of my tongue but I can't remember it at all and it's killing me.

Comment: Why doesn't "bound" work?

Comment: We don't really say "to be at the whim of somebody". We do say do something on a whim. "subjected to her bidding". to be a someone's beck and call.

Answer (score 2):

> [Character] made a contract with the [Demon Name] and is now **in
> thrall** to her / in her **thrall**.

**thrall (n.) / in thrall to** (idiom)

> **thrall** (n.)
>
> If you say that someone is **in thrall to** a person or thing, you
> mean that they are completely in their power or are greatly influenced
> by them.
> [*formal*]
>
> *He is not **in thrall to** the media.*
>
> *Tomorrow's children will be even more **in the thrall of** the silicon chip.*
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thrall)

> **thrall** (n.)
>
> 1. The state of being in the power of another person or under the sway of an influence: "*a people **in thrall to** the miracles of commerce*"
>    (Lewis H. Lapham).
> 2. a. One, such as a slave or serf, who is held in bondage.
>    b. One who is in the power of another or under the sway of an influence
>    [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=thrall)

> **in thrall** (idiom)
> *literary*
>
> In a state of being controlled or strongly influenced by someone or something
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20thrall)

---

> By focusing on men and women engages in specific sins, the woods cuts
> tended to support the view that only obvious wrongdoers were **in
> thrall to the Devil.**
> [Darren Oldridge *The Devil in Tudor and Stuart
> England*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZlU7AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&dq=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20devil&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFmtb0kN6CAxUTEFkFHUK-AeYQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20devil&f=false) (2011)

> 'So, Amos, between Arthur Beford and the Baron, you have been
> harnessed to two evil taskmasters, have you not? Men who have used you
> for their own ends. But you seem not to have resisted them. You were
> ***in thrall***? Is that your plea?'
> [David Fairer; *The Devil's Cathedral: A Mystery of Queen Anne's London*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jR5GEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA557&dq=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20devil&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFmtb0kN6CAxUTEFkFHUK-AeYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20devil&f=false) (2021)

> Even President Karzai has publicly acknowledged the overwhelming
> corruption and the immense harm it has wreaked upon the country. Even
> Karzai's family has been linked to opium smugglers. According to a
> former Afghan finance minister, "the government has lost the capacity
> to govern" and is completely **in thrall to** drug traffickers.
> [Martin
> Biegelman and Daniel Biegelman; *Overview of the Foreign Corrupt Practices
> Act*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GYmon_COXMgC&pg=PT20&dq=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20drug%20lords&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2-JC8mN6CAxUQE1kFHX7PBUA4HhDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=in%20thrall%20to%20the%20drug%20lords&f=false) (2010)

> Themistius' Procopius *had* to be in control of information, to be
> able to bend unwilling subjects to his will, and to keep them **in his
> thrall**, in order to exonerate his colleagues in the senate.
> [Adrastos Omissi; *Emperors and Usurpers in the Later Roman
> Empire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EWliDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA250&dq=%22in%20his%20thrall%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv7PXzwN-CAxVXFVkFHYCBDigQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22in%20his%20thrall%22&f=false) (2018)